# How to extract all the required definitions from header files in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, header, g++, definition

I would like to know how can one produce (either using `gcc` or an external tool) a single `.h` file that contains only the definitions of the types and functions used in the `.cpp` file.

For example: let's say I have multiple header files that contain a lot of functions (including their implementations) and I have a `.cpp` file that includes a single header file which in turns include all the other header files.

Inside the single `.cpp` file I call a function `abc(some_argument);` and I want to somehow grab only all the parts of code that I need for `abc(some_argument)` to work. Kind of producing a single header file that contains only the definitions required for `abc(some_argument)`.

I know this idea might sound crazy, probable ugly, but I really need something like that.

Thank you!!